# Is it worth to delete object properties when the object itself is not needed?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

Let's say I have the following code:

```
function foo(myobj, otherobj){
    var obj = {};
    obj.first = myobj; // a really big object
    obj.second = otherobj; // another big object

    // some work with "obj"

    delete obj; // can't do that
}
```

I've read quite a lot about `delete` in Javascript, but I still can't grasp it so well. I know that I can delete only properties of an object and variables without DontDelete. In the code above, I obviously can't delete `obj`, but will it be worth to delete its properties like that:

```
function foo(myobj, otherobj){
    var obj = {};
    obj.first = myobj; // a really big object
    obj.second = otherobj; // another big object

    // some work with "obj"

    delete obj.first;
    delete obj.second;
    // obj is now empty "{}"
}
```

I have the following questions:

- Am I really helping the browser by doing those deletions?
- Am I deleting only the references by `obj` to `myobj` and `otherobj` provided from the arguments or `obj.first` and `obj.second` are copies of `myobj` and `otherobj` and I actually delete something meaningful?
- Let's say I have access to the original `myobj` and `otherobj`, not their references. Since I no longer need them, how to remove them?
- When to use `delete` if my goal is to boost performance? Is there something that will make a significant difference?
- Will I be OK if I just make sure to leave no circular references so that the garbage collector can do its job? Is that what `delete` is for?

I would appreciate any information about `delete`, even if it's not related to my questions. :)

Comment: Set `obj` to `null`, and the garbage collector will be guaranteed to start doing its thing. In your case though, it will be deleted when the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: You're overthinking this. JavaScript is garbage-collected. So any instance that reaches a refcount of 0 (either by `delete` or by reaching the end of it's scope) will be cleared out by the engine. You don't need to explicitly delete anything,

Comment: @MadaraUchiha is it the same with Node.js?

Comment: @HristiyanDodov Yes.